# How to show the key and the values of my JSON on Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

`my code is this:  [*ngFor="let m of Markets | keyvalue">{{m.key | json}} {{m.value | json}}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6oup.png)

the problem is that the key is 0,1,2,3,4,5 not TMALL and JD and the value is tmall and all the array that is inside so i want to separate that.

It's a strange problem because the JSON of the database is this one:
[{"tmall":["vino","aceite","chocolate","lacteos","cafe","cerveza","bebidas","licores","comida para bebe","conservas"]},
{"JD":["vino","aceite","chocolate","lacteos","cafe","cerveza","bebidas","licores","comida para bebe","conservas"]}

Comment: Please consider to edit your question adding snippets (code inside ``` delimiters) and some reproducible code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

your model is a list, not a map. You should nest two ngFor, one regular and another one with `| keyvalue`

```
<div *ngFor="let m1 of Markets">
    <div *ngFor="let m2 of m1 | keyvalue">{{m2.key | json}} {{m2.value | json}}></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works!!!! thanks Sir

Comment: @Alvaromasa1 So if you could upvote and validate my answer, it would be kind!

Comment: btw `| json` on the `m2.key` binding is useless. You can remove it